# Go through the address ranges of data validation

Tags: vba, excel

Given a worksheet with several data validations, I would like to write a piece of vba code to go though these ranges.

I know that `ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Address` returns the address of all the ranges. For instance, if `$A$1:$C$4` has a validation whose type is `xlValidateWholeNumber` and `$E$8:$G$9` has a validation whose type is `xlValidateTextLength`, `ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Address` returns `$A$1:$C$4, $E$8:$G$9`. Then I don't know how to manipulate this result to study `$A$1:$C$4` and then `$E$8:$G$9`, to print the ranges and their details of validation (type, ErrorTitle...).

Could anyone tell me if there is a function to split the result of `Address`?

Otherwise, is there another way to go through all the data validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will alert each separate "block" of cells:

```
Dim rng As Range, a as Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error Goto 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        MsgBox a.Address(false,false)
    Next a
Else
    MsgBox "No validation found"
End If
```